# Passive "led" followed by ("into" and gerund) or ("to" and infinitive)?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-choice, infinitive-vs-gerund

Which of those two sentences is correct?

> 1. People were led **into thinking** that method X was beneficial for Y.

or

> 2. People were led **to think** that method X was beneficial for Y.

Perhaps you also have an explanation why one or the other is correct?

**EDIT**

It is safe to assume that all words unrelated to the question (words that are neither the preposition after "led" nor a form of the verb "think") are correct and there is no need to point out that *those* could be incorrect, depending on the context of use.

Comment: Are you speaking of a situation where people were a) intentionally or b) unintentionally... led to/into a 1) true or 2) false  conclusion? There are four possibilities there, each with a best way to express it.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock I assumed "lead into thinking / lead to think" always meant arriving at a _false_ conclusion. But anyway: I am describing a situation were people are unintentionally led to a false conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

When you *lead* X *{infinitive}*, you are saying that you are causing X to do or be in a state of doing the verb identified in the infinitive.

When you *lead* X *into* Y, you are saying that you are causing X to be moved (i.e. bringing X) *inside of/within/surrounded by* Y - that's what the preposition *in*/*into* means.'

With *lead* X *into* Y, Y can be a gerund, which makes it mean the same as *lead X {infinitive}*, but possibly with a slight implication that X did not originally plan to do Y.  This distinction, if it exists, probably matters more in written text, like in a story, than in conversation.

> We followed the map which led us to walk down this path.
>
> That crazy squirrel led us into walking down this path.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting hypothesis! But I assumed "into" and "to" to be highly grammaticalized in this case and thought they have lost their original spatial meaning in this process of becoming part of the grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Both are probably correct but the latter is better in my opinion. They both mean the same thing and it is shorter and simpler.

Comment: You're saying both are "probably correct" - what makes you unsure about their correctness? I'm interested in whether one of them (or both) are definitely correct.

Comment: @Mathias - It's hard to say that something is absolutely correct when there is little surrounding context. For example, if only one person was led to believe something, then _people_ would not be the right word to use.

Comment: Examples of both can be found in published books, but the shorter and simpler version seems to be [strongly preferred](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=led+to+think%2Cled+into+thinking%2Cled+to+believe%2Cled+into+believing&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) in writing. This answer provides sound guidance; I'm led to think the lone downvote seems rather harsh.

Comment: @J.R. I'm aware of the meaning of "people", but I see what you are implying. I meant to ask about the correctness of both sentences, given that all words that are neither the preposition after "led" nor a form of the verb "think" are definitely correct. I did not downvote, by the way - and I appreciate the pun :-).

Comment: Also, @J.R., perhaps you could turn your comments into an answer?

Comment: @Mathias - I'd rather wait and see if Nick wants to improve this answer. It's on the right track, and he's free to incorporate my Ngram into his answer to support his assertion, if he'd like to do so.

Comment: The reason I wrote "probably correct" is because you can find many written instances of both and both forms are used by native speakers. However, in grammatical matters it doesn't do to be too dogmatic and somebody better qualified than me (or I!) may know something I don't.

Answer (score 0):

> (1) People were led into thinking that method X was beneficial for Y.
>
> (2) People were led to think that method X was beneficial for Y.

I like (2) better.  "led to" jives better with the sentence, the way you set it up.

Example of "led into": *From years of brainwashing, I had been led into thinking of fats and oils as the bad guy in nutrition.*  This construction is often used to suggest some type of "leading down the garden path," in other words, there's some misleading or deception going on.  It can be used in other ways, but still, this is pretty common.  And that is the feeling that I get from (1).

*Lead to think* doesn't usually have that connotation.

It's possible I was jumping to conclusions about what you were trying to express... but at any rate, now you'll be able to choose, depending on your degree of skepticism!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, does "led to think that method X was beneficial for Y" actually include the possibility that X _really is_ beneficial for Y?